# How to display Paypal variables on return page

Tags: php, paypal

The following is the code for my return page.  It runs fine and completes successfully.  I am assuming, since the page is successful then the variables in $requestParams are available on the page.  What is the correct syntax to display the values of the variables in $requestParams

```
<?php
require_once '../library/DPayPal.php'; //Import library


$token=$_GET["token"];//Returned by paypal, you can save this in SESSION too
$paypal = new DPaypal();
$requestParams = array('TOKEN' => $token);

$response = $paypal->GetExpressCheckoutDetails($requestParams);
$payerId=$response["PAYERID"];//Payer id returned by paypal

//Create request for DoExpressCheckoutPayment
$requestParams=array(
    "TOKEN"=>$token,
    "PAYERID"=>$payerId,
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"=>"20",//Payment amount. This value should be sum of of item values, if there are more items in order
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"=>"USD",//Payment currency
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"=>"20"//Item amount
);
$transactionResponse=$paypal->DoExpressCheckoutPayment($requestParams);//Execute transaction

if(is_array($transactionResponse) && $transactionResponse["ACK"]=="Success"){//Payment was successfull

echo "Successfull";

//  Displays Successfull, but NONE of the following commands display any results


print_r($transactionResponse["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]);
echo $transactionResponse["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"];

print_r($transactionResponse);
echo $transactionResponse;
}



else{

echo "Failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: `print_r($requestParams);` just like you did with `$transactionResponse`, but they are available because you defined it on this page not because anything was successful.

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  Thanks AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see the data dumped out for your own reference you can do the same thing you did with $transactionResponse.  If you want to display the values for users to see you could do something like this.

```
foreach($requestParams as $var => $val)
{
    echo $var . ': ' . $val . '<br />';
}
```